# Schengen Visa, FInancial Proof

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, proof-of-funds

me and my cousin are planning to have a short euro trip. I have sufficient account balance with regular income so for me everything is fine but my cousin didn't maintain the account and he withdraws full salary as soon as it comes. 
He can provide the bank statement but the point is there won't be any funds as he usually never leaves anything in the account. So in this case can I write a letter or something that I will be responsible for all his expenses. I am having enough funds to support both us.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Atleast in my home country (in EU), migration services in such cases only accept bank statements, except for few specific cases, so I believe your friend will just have to leave some funds on the bank account.

Source: having a friend from Ukraine who currently lives in EU.

Answer (score 2):

The visa officials want to see your bank statements to determine if you are a genuine tourist or an illegal immigrant. Part of the check is to see if you and your brother can *reasonably* afford the trip.

- They will check your bank balance to see if you can pay the likely costs of the trip. A traveler who has to borrow money to afford the trip looks like an illegal immigrant. (Note: sudden unexplained deposits are a bad idea.)
- They will check for regular deposits and withdrawals to see how much of your disposable income goes into the trip. A traveler who has saved for many years and now wants to spend all that money on a week-long vacation looks like an illegal immigrant because reasonable tourists wouldn't do that. (Unless they just retired, or some investment came due, or whatever.)

That means they **really** want to see your brother's bank statements. Why can't he start to pay some major bills from his account before he withdraws the rest?